# Problema con Entity Framework, la tabla o vista no tiene una clave principal

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, web, entity-framework

Tengo un pequeño crud en mvc asp.net y entity framework, funciona todo bien, solo que se me pidio usar una vista para agregar al crud, en todo caso esta vista no tiene una clave principal y al momento de quere agregar la vista me salta ese error, hay alguna forma de poder arreglar esto sin modificar la vista?, adjunto la vista de ejemplo:

```
create view view_Prueba as
select nombre, garantia, region, sucursal
from region, prueba 
where idprue=idprue
```

Comment: Una Vista es para mostrar datos del tipo `readonly`, si vas a modificar algo, sí o sí necesitas una llave que te muestre el dato en particular, sin ese dato ¿cómo llegarías a esa fila que quieres modificar?

Comment: @fredyfx (jaaja lo edite, mé confundi de pagina) respecto a la pregunta, los datos de la vista no los voy a modificar solamente es para traer los datos a un formulario que recien se me van a guardar en una tabla aparte.